# Why am I getting Javascript errors/ unable to save when creating a new mailing?

Tags: wordpress, civimail

Trying to figure out why I keep getting javascript errors and not being able to save when trying to create a new civimail mailing on WordPress / CiviCRM 4.7.27. It is a fresh install. Not sure what is going on.

Anybody have any good ideas on why this may be happening?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the specific javascript errors.

Comment: What is the content of the mailing? Does it happen if you have simple text content in the body of the mailing?

Comment: Got rid of WP Super Cache and Wordfence. No longer getting the errors. Thanks for the help tho!

Comment: @DetroitSherpa this would make a great answer! Don't worry you can answer your own question (and accept the answer) - and this might help future Wordpress users!

Answer (score 3):

Got rid of WP Super Cache and Wordfence. No longer getting the errors. Thanks for the help tho!

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/7345)

Comment: @Xavier this is the only answer and I think in this case it is helpful to post it as an answer as it could be helpful to others.